# UITableView is working fine in simulator but not in my physical device

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am currently building an Application which shows all the faculties that are available in my college. I have the data in a .plist file which I have read and populated in the UITableView. I am currently trying to show some details such as prefix and Name in the cell which when clicked on Expands to show more details about the faculty.

My TableViewController Code is shown below:

```swift
struct cellData {
    var opened = Bool()
    var Name = String()
    var Prefix = String()
    var sectionData = [String]()
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //MARK: - Initialize variables
    var dataManager = DataManager()
    private var header = [String]()
    private var facultyDetails = [[String: String]]()
    var tableViewData = [cellData]()
    @IBOutlet var facultyTableView: UITableView!


    //MARK: - view did load

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for data in dataManager.allSheet1s() {
            let dataInCell = cellData(opened: false, Name: data.item2!,
                                      Prefix: data.item1!, sectionData  [data.item0!,
                                                                         data.item2!,
                                                                         data.item1!,
                                                                         data.item3!,
                                                                         data.item4!,
                                                                         data.item5!,
                                                                         data.item6!,
                                                                         data.item7!,
                                                                         data.item8!,
                                                                         data.item9!,
                                                                         data.item10!
                ])

            tableViewData.append(dataInCell)

            facultyTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
        }


    }

    // MARK: - Table view delegate

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return tableViewData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 1
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomCell

        if indexPath.row == 0 {


            cell.EmpID.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[0]
            cell.Name.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[1]
            cell.Prefix.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[2]
            cell.SchoolName.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[3]
            cell.BuildingName.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[4]
            cell.FloorNo.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[5]
            cell.CabinLocation.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[6]
            cell.RoomNo.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[7]
            cell.CabinNo.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[8]
            cell.IntercomNumber.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[9]
            cell.Email.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[10]

            return cell
        }
       return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened == true {
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = false

            let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .right)

        }
        else {
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = true

            let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .left)


        }
    }



    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened == true {
            return 400
        }
        else {
            return 70
        }
    }
}
```

[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Els2q.jpg)

[Physical Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dwC3.jpg)

Right now you can see in the simulator that it works perfectly fine. But when I load it up in the physical device the height of each cell in the rows are clipping through the other cells below it.

Comment: Is the simulator and physical device the same iPhone type?  For example simulator is iPhone 8 and physical device is iPhone Xr.  Inside IB you can select the various device types.

Comment: Simulator is ios13 iPhone XR and physical device is ios12.2 iPhone XR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your cell for row code by adding cell.clipsToBounds = true

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomCell

        cell.clipsToBounds = true

        if indexPath.row == 0 {


            cell.EmpID.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[0]
            cell.Name.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[1]
            cell.Prefix.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[2]
            cell.SchoolName.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[3]
            cell.BuildingName.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[4]
            cell.FloorNo.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[5]
            cell.CabinLocation.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[6]
            cell.RoomNo.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[7]
            cell.CabinNo.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[8]
            cell.IntercomNumber.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[9]
            cell.Email.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[10]

            return cell
        }
       return cell
    }
```

And override a method

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 70
    }
```